# How come serial cables LEDs don't get dimmed instead of switching on and off when sending serial data?

Tags: led, serial, cables

This is I would say less researched question because I couldn't really find any interesting on net and I am noob and people around me are not so resourceful when it comes to electronics hardware. I asked my mate who does hardware mostly at my job but his answer doesn't satisfy me because he said they have controller inside that switches it on and off at a frequency so that it doesn't dim.

But when I am using serial cable to send/recieve data, I don't find a continuous pattern of simply switching on and off, it seem(idk maybe) but it seems like it is switching on when it encounters high and switching off when it encounters low. The baudrates I have confirmed it not be dim is from 4800-38600.

I believe it would be more like PWM so it should expect it to dim?

The serial to USB here in question is ATC-810.

I suspect there is some kind of hardware magic lying there. I would love to know that. I don't expect exact schematics. But just tell me how do they do it basically?

Comment: If you have a scope you can see what's actually happening with the LED; it may be continuously driven.

Comment: @pjc50 Never did that hit my head. Would an Cheap imitation of Logic analyser do? I can't open that cable at job and at home I can't afford a Oscilloscope!

Comment: Logic analyser should at least show it going up and down and whether that's the same as the serial data or not. It won't show you if there's a curve, characteristic of the LED being powered by a capacitor for short periods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can assure you that you can dim LEDs by attaching them to serial lines and switching them on and off by sending specifically prepared data. I've done that.

The reason you're not seeing dimming might be:

- Your colleague is right, and the controller chip simply keeps the LED on for as long as there's communication and a while longer, so that it never turns off in between
- brightness perception isn't linear. So, turning off the LED for 1/8 of the time, for example, simple won't be visible to the human eye.

Comment: Could also be a matter of probability. If serial chars have an equal numbers of 1's and 0's, they will be seen equally dim, and you just see it turn off in between chars.